# Strange! Static const unsigned is not a constant expression in class template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Code is here. Compiler is VC++ 2012.

```
template<class T> // Normal class is okay. But template has the problem.
class A
{
    const static unsigned N = 2; // not okay

    // enum {N = 2}; // this is okay

    template<unsigned i> void Fun() {}

    template<> void Fun<N>() {} // error C2975 not constant expression
};
```

Why? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of `N` and use `Fun<2>` and you should get the same errors, at least on GCC 4.8.1 (I assume VS would have them, but you didn't post the errors). That really has an effect on the title of your question.

Comment: @chris I corrected my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler may be giving the wrong error message, but the code is ill-formed because `template<>` is invalid inside a `class {}` scope. That declares an explicit specialization, which can only appear at namespace scope.

Unfortunately you cannot specialize a class template member function template, except for under an explicit class template specialization (which isn't a class template any more).

Try using overloading and SFINAE instead. Function template specialization is generally a bad idea.

```
template<unsigned i> typename std::enable_if< i != N >::type Fun() {}
template<unsigned i> typename std::enable_if< i == N >::type Fun() {}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. When you say invalid, does it mean not compilable? What your Fun() suppose to do? When Fun<N>() is called, a compilation error is given? Thanks.

Comment: @user1899020 The compiler should give up as soon as it sees `template<>` inside a `class {}`. Yes, invalid means won't compile. If the compiler never compiled a declaration for `Fun`, then if it ever proceeds to `Fun<N>` that will also cause another error. If you use my suggested declarations, and they do work in your program, then `Fun<2>` and `Fun<1>` would dispatch to the different functions as you seem to desire.